# A lot of csproj files spawned in Visual Studio Code - can I delete them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was just typing some code for a unity project and then my computer crashed. Luckily I saved it right before the crash, so nothing got lost (except some things in unity). I opened vscode and in my project i saw a bunch of .csproj files with hundreds of lines, and it is kind of annoying me.

I'm kind of new to coding so I don't know if it is safe to delete these files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These csproj are automatically generated by Unity, but they can be turned off if you dont need them. Open Preferences > External tools and turn all of them off.  You should still see all your Unity assembly definitions.
[image: csproj files might be disable]

- You might need to remove them and regenearet your project files with "Regenerate project files" button in the same dialog

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue when opening Visual Studio for my Unity project.

I can delete them without causing any problem, but they are created at each opening of the project in VS.